# FFMpeg mixing audio to video creates silent video after audio is added,

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

mixing audio to video creates silent video after audio is added, using FFMpeg

this is the command I am using

```
"-y","-i",j,"-filter_complex","amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,atrim=0:18,adelay=50000|50000,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=2.0[a2];[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]","-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

I have a video which is 2 mins 7 seconds ling, I want to  'mix' audio to a part starting from 50 seconds to 68 seconds

What i want is to keep original sound from video and mix audio to existing sound of video(not over write) it, **(keep old video sound and new audio in video)**

what happens is till 50 seconds video has its own sound, from 50 -68 the audio over writes the video sound and from then till end it is silent

**what i want is video to have its sound through out the video and mix from 50 -68 seconds the audio to it**

this graphic can explain a bit of what i want and what i am getting

**What i want** [image]
**what i am getting**[image]
**another problem that I am facing is
if i try this on a silent video (video with no sound at all) this code fails this is the error that I am getting**

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/abcd/Videos/20180325_164206.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-03-25 16:44:15
  Duration: 00:02:05.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1585 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 1584 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16, 11.83 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-25 16:44:15
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
[mp3 @ 0xaca26b40] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 417.
[Parsed_pan_9 @ 0xac9b17e0] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description amovie=/storage/sdcard0/abcd/Videos/baby.mp3:loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,atrim=0:18,adelay=50000|50000,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=2.0[a2]; [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out] matches no streams.
```

**how can we add audio to a silent video**

Comment: Try amix instead of amerge.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit,with the command

Comment: Replace amerge with amix and remove the pan. It'll extend the audio till the end. The video's audio disappearing between 50-68 is weird, but check with amix.

Comment: this is the new command i have tried "-y","-i",j,"-filter_complex","amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB," +"atrim=0:18,adelay=50000|50000,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];" +"[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=2.0[a2];" +" [a1][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2[out]","-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-preset", "ultrafast", out,   still it has the same issue , no sound after new audio added